# SQL Server Management Studio says this statement is incorrect

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio to test some SQL queries, and the query below is said to have 'incorrect syntax near ','', which is the comma after 'image_uuid'. I read up on the syntax and I think I'm listing the columns correctly.

I need to move rows from one table to an archive table. I will be using this statement, then after drop the rows that I moved. If there's a cleaner way to do this, please explain what else I can do. Thanks!

```
INSERT INTO litmus_mailing_archive(image_uuid, server_id, list_id, mailing_id,
                   litmus_job_id, email_subject, test_email_message_id,
                   test_running, test_started, test_finished,
                   ended_with_error, images_purged, notification_email)
    SELECT 
        (image_uuid, server_id, list_id, mailing_id, 
         litmus_job_id, email_subject, test_email_message_id, 
         test_running, test_started, test_finished, 
         ended_with_error, images_purged, notification_email)
    FROM   
        litmus_mailing
    WHERE  
        server_id = ?
        AND list_id = ?
        AND mailing_id = ?
        AND test_running = 'false';
```

The question marks are just placeholders for the info. When I test it, I insert actual data that is in `litmus_mailing`.

Comment: I take it the error is after the second `image_uuid`? In that case, it's the `(` around the columns in your SELECT statement, AFAICT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the parentheses from the select query:

```
SELECT (image_uuid, server_id, list_id, mailing_id, 
litmus_job_id, email_subject, test_email_message_id, 
test_running, test_started, test_finished, ended_with_error, 
images_purged, notification_email)
```

Change it to this:

```
SELECT image_uuid, server_id, list_id, mailing_id, 
litmus_job_id, email_subject, test_email_message_id, 
test_running, test_started, test_finished, 
ended_with_error, images_purged, notification_email
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parentheses around the SELECT field list.